# Left Join with Distinct Right table returns more rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have two tables, one is my `Main` table and one is `Mapping` table. The simplified tables look like this :

Main :

```
VALUE | CUSTNAME
123 | ADELE
323 | GORTH
242 | GORTH
345 | VIX
...
```

Mapping :

```
ISSUER | CATEGORY 
ADELE | A
GORTH | B
DENN | B
VIX | C
...
```

What I want to do is add a `CATEGORY` column to my `Main` table, so I to use a left join, but somehow it returns more rows than I originally have. And I can't check it one by one because it has around 30000 records. The increase it self is miniscule, 40 records, but it still a difference and it shows.

Things to note and things I already tried :

- `Main` table can hold the same `CUSTNAME` while `Mapping` table is distinct, making it many-to-one relation.
- `Mapping` table holds duplicate records, so I tried to select distinct it first before joining it
- I already checked the NULL to see if the `Mapping` table miss anything, but it doesn't seems to be the case
- I use both inner join and left join but it return the same result

So what did I do wrong here and how can I fix it?

My query :

```
SELECT A.*, B.CATEGORY AS CATEGORY
FROM Main A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Mapping) B ON A.CUSTNAME = B.Issuer
```

My output right now :

```
 VALUE | CUSTNAME | CATEGORY
    123 | ADELE | A
    323 | GORTH | B
    242 | GORTH | B
    345 | VIX | C
    ... with extra 40 records
```

My expected output :

```
 VALUE | CUSTNAME | CATEGORY
    123 | ADELE | A
    323 | GORTH | B
    242 | GORTH | B
    345 | VIX | C
    ... without extra 40 records
```

Comment: Your current and expected outputs appear the same.  Is there a typo here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows if you are looking to eliminate duplicates Mapping.Issuer ONLY.

```
SELECT A.*, B.CATEGORY AS CATEGORY
FROM Main A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Issuer, MAX(CATEGORY) AS CATEGORY FROM Mapping group by Issuer) B ON A.CUSTNAME = B.Issuer
```

Probably you have data on Mapping table like :

```
insert into Mapping values 
('ADELE','A'),
('GORTH','B'),
('DENN','B'),
('VIX','C'),
('VIX','D');
```

That means `('VIX','C'), ('VIX','D')` are not duplicates

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ebhd3HFE)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. ('VIX','C'), ('VIX','D') shouldn't be a problem because I know VIX is always C. Distinct * is the problem after all

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Mapping
```

won't prevent duplicates. `Distinct *` means that the tuple(combination) of ALL columns will be considered as unique; However, if there are two rows with same Issuer but a different value in *any* of the other columns, it will still return multiple rows. Like this:

```
Issuer | ManufactureId 
5623     894 
5623     895
```

This, in turn, will make one row from A turn into multiple from the `left join`.

Comment: okay, duly noted. Then how can I select both Issuer and Category, but only Distinct the 'issuer'? Since I need both Issuer and Category

Comment: If there are many rows for the same issuer, it means there may be many different categories too. If so, which category would you want? If you can define a preference via an `order by`, we can make the neccessary query.

Comment: Just check the raw file, Category is actually the same through out (A,B,C). It's the Issuer that has duplicates, distinct * probably didn't pick it up because Mapping has other columns and not exactly look like the example I provide. Either way the Answer above actually fix my problem, Thank you for your explanation!